# Why does Scala construct a new Tuple when unpacking a Tuple?

Tags: scala, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Why does this Scala code:

```
class Test
{
  def foo: (Int, String) =
  {
    (123, "123")
  }

  def bar: Unit =
  {
    val (i, s) = foo
  }
}
```

generate the following bytecode for `bar()` that constructs a new `Tuple2`, passes the `Tuple2` from `foo()` to it and then gets the values out of it?

```
public void bar();
Code:
 0:   aload_0
 1:   invokevirtual   #28; //Method foo:()Lscala/Tuple2;
 4:   astore_2
 5:   aload_2
 6:   ifnull  40
 9:   new     #7; //class scala/Tuple2
 12:  dup
 13:  aload_2
 14:  invokevirtual   #32; //Method scala/Tuple2._1:()Ljava/lang/Object;
 17:  aload_2
 18:  invokevirtual   #35; //Method scala/Tuple2._2:()Ljava/lang/Object;
 21:  invokespecial   #20; //Method scala/Tuple2."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
 24:  astore_1
 25:  aload_1
 26:  invokevirtual   #39; //Method scala/Tuple2._1$mcI$sp:()I
 29:  istore_3
 30:  aload_1
 31:  invokevirtual   #35; //Method scala/Tuple2._2:()Ljava/lang/Object;
 34:  checkcast       #41; //class java/lang/String
 37:  astore  4
```

Is this because the compiler isn't checking that `foo()`s return value isn't a tuple?

Will the JVM optimize the construction away anyway?

Comment: `foo`'s return value _is_ a tuple. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: foo does return a type, but at 9: in bar() it constructs a new tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be according to the [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (in *4.1 Value Declarations and Definitions* - slightly reformatted for stackoverflow display):

> Value definitions can alternatively have a pattern (§8.1) as left-hand side. If p is some pattern other than a simple name or a name followed by a colon and a type, then the value definition `val p = e` is expanded as follows:
>
> 1. If the pattern `p` has bound variables `x1, . . . , xn`, where `n >= 1`:
>      Here, `$x` is a fresh name.

```
  val $x = e match {case p => (x1, . . . , xn)}
  val x1 = $x._1
  . . .
  val xn = $x._n
```

So the tuple creation happens in the parser phase. So `val (i, s) = (1, "s")` expends at the end of the parser phase to:

```
private[this] val x$1 = scala.Tuple2(1, "s"): @scala.unchecked match {    
  case scala.Tuple2((i @ _), (s @ _)) => scala.Tuple2(i, s)
};
val i = x$1._1;
val s = x$1._2
```

Measuring this on this simple test on a million iterations:

```
def foo: (Int, String) = (123, "123")
def bar: Unit = { val (i, s) = foo }
def bam: Unit = { val f = foo; val i = f._1; val s = f._2 }
```

yields

```
foo: Elapsed: 0.030
bar: Elapsed: 0.051
._1 ._2 access: Elapsed: 0.040
```

and with -optimize flag:

```
foo: Elapsed: 0.027
bar: Elapsed: 0.049
._1 ._2 access: Elapsed: 0.029
```

Comment: Thanks.  BTW, the Scala 2.9 compiler with and without -optimize generates the same bytecode for the Test class I pasted, but perhaps it helped out on the benchmarking code to make the times faster.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like a missed optimization opportunity in scalac.

The relevant part of the compiler us [Unapplies#caseClassUnapplyReturnValue](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/aa5a8b1651e46fd65e7333bcce4d3af75d1edc23/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Unapplies.scala#L118), which calls `TreeDSL#SOME` to generate code to create a new `TupleN`